# the usage of memory is so high on linux

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I found memory usage is so high.
And i checked it via top command, only 66664k free, my computer's total memory is 12GB.
I checked all processes via system monitor software, found all processes cost about 200MB memory.

1. Why does top command say only 60kb memory is free?
2. Sometimes, i found some processes cost memory about 10TB and they
   free the memory at once. anybody tell me? thanks.

Comment: If you Google this, you'll find about a million hits as to how Linux uses memory.

Comment: Unused memory is pretty much wasted. Preloading, Caching etc. will use RAM while other processes don´t.

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is — cache. Don't worry too much, used memory means it's not just collecting dust. It still can be used for other purposes, though.

Comment: but my workstation is so slow that i have to restart it.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried with `htop`?

To install on a Debian-based system:
`apt-get install htop`

Legend:
1. `Green`  = `Used Memory`
2. Blue   = Buffers
3. Yellow = Cache

Comment: +1 for bringing _htop_ to my attention. It's pretty sweet!